# Variation Raabe's Test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_n >0$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(a_n/a_{n+1} -1) = \alpha$.

If $\alpha > 0$, is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$ converges?

I know that Raabe's test says that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if $\alpha > 1$ and diverges if $\alpha < 1$. So from absolute convergence we know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$ converges for $\alpha > 1$, but I can't determine what happens if $0 < \alpha \leqslant 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $0 < r < \alpha$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geqslant N$ we have $n(a_n/a_{n+1} - 1) > r$ and

$$\tag{*}\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} > 1 + \frac{r}{n} \geqslant 1.$$

Thus $a_{n+1} < a_n$ and the sequence is decreasing.

Furthermore, by repeated application of (*) we see that

$$\frac{a_N}{a_n} > \prod_{k=N}^{n-1}\left(1 + \frac{r}{k} \right) > \sum_{k=N}^{n-1} \frac{r}{k}$$

Since $\sum 1/k$ diverges, so too does the infinite product $\prod (1 + r/k)$, and it follows that $a_n \to 0.$

By the alternating series test, $\sum (-1)^na_n$ must converge.